# Find the sum of inverse functions

Tags: inverse-function

$y=\sin^{-1}(\sin 8)-\tan^{-1}(\tan 10)+\cos^{-1}(\cos 12)-
\sec^{-1}(\sec 9)+\cot^{-1}(\cot 6)-\csc^{-1}(\csc 7)$.

If $y$ simplifies to $y=aπ+b$, then find $a-b$.

My answer is zero.

But the answer is ***53***. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, no one can know where you've gone wrong without looking at how you tried to solve the problem. Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I used the concept $sin^{-1}sin8=\theta$, hence $\theta=8$, summing i get zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Using [principal values of inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$$2\pi<8<3\pi\implies\sin^{-1}(\sin8)=3\pi-8$$

$$3\pi<10<4\pi\implies\tan^{-1}(\tan10)=10-3\pi$$